# How can I input in table math mode?

Tags: tables

```
\hline
    a & b & c & a/b & sqrt a/b & N1/N2 \bigstrut\\
```

Comment: Just do as you would do normally (`$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$`).

Answer (score 3):

For example, environment `array` (in math mode):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  $\begin{array}{cccccc}
  a & b & c & a/b & \sqrt{a/b} & N_1/N_2
  \end{array}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with environment array]

Explicit math mode setting in environment `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}    
  \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
  $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $a/b$ & $\sqrt{a/b}$ & $N_1/N_2$
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with tabular]

If the cells belong to a matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  $\begin{matrix}
  a & b & c & a/b & \sqrt{a/b} & N_1/N_2
  \end{matrix}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with environment matrix]

Answer (score 0):

When you write a table, every entry is just normal text so you can just write normal text in every entry:

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
I'm totally text    &     Me To    &    I'm Also text\\
This means that     &     You can  &    Easily just put\\
Math in each entry!  &    $\alpha$ &    $ \frac{cool math}{here}$
\end{tabular}
```

Produces:

[image]

I have removed the last line from the code, since it was wronger than i thought

Comment: sorry but this is completely wrong, you are missing `$\\ `  to end the second row and using `equation` in a `c` column does not work at all it produces the error `! You can't use \`\eqno' in restricted horizontal mode.`

Comment: @David.Carlisle thanks for pointing it out. I wrote the example on tex.se, and then tested it out and found the errors afterwards. Thought I remembered to correct them, but it seems I didn't. The errors will be fixed within a minute or two of this comment ;-).

Comment: it's still wrong! you added the `$\\ ` but the main error, the `equation` is still there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I actually did this on purpose to show that you could, if you wanted to, put displaymath in tables, but i guess that I was wrong, and that I just hadn't realized how much (I tried to write some fractions inside the equation, and everything went buncers) Thanks for pointing it out again ;-)